# Can a community edit its How to Ask page?

Tags: support, asking-questions

The How To Ask page is written for Stack Overflow only. If the community desires to edit its How to Ask page to be better adapted to its site, can they?

I asked it [on Skeptics' meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/how-can-we-personalize-our-how-to-ask-page) but got no answer.

Comment: +1: Good point.  I don't think many people think about this because no one with >200 rep ever sees it.

Comment: I guess that's the problem with Skeptics' Meta. Who's going to believe there's a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is static across the network.

> This page is currently static across the network - it isn't set up to be customized per site.  That is a fairly significant change, so it would need to be a separate feature request.
>
> <sub>[How can we personalize our How to Ask page?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/how-can-we-personalize-our-how-to-ask-page/212#212)</sub>

<sub><sup>Guess this is a bit backwards now. (;</sup></sub>

Comment: No m'am, *this* is backwards :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not written for "Stack Overflow only".

It is written generically for *question and answer sites on our engine*.

Comment: "A lot of what we do is as much an art as a science, so a conclusive answer isn’t always possible" might sense on a site about programming. It doesn't make much sense on a site about physics or mathematics.

Comment: @bor no problem, I will change it to "A conclusive answer isn't always possible."