# Improving "How to ask" page readability

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, serverfault

This proposal comes in two parts.

First of all, I think that "**How to ask**" page lacks readability at the moment and therefore is ignored by most new users. A simple CSS change will make things much better, as shown in included images. They use the following values:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.subheader h1 {
    color: #242729;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 2.22;
}

p {
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 150%;
}
```

**Current page:**

[image]

**Proposed changes:**

[image]

The second part is about an ability to customize **"How to ask"** pages for each site. Is there any updates on this [long-time requested feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83043/allow-each-se-site-to-customize-its-how-to-ask-page)? On serverfault we got an every day problem with people whos first question is an offtopic/gets closed. If we could include [this guide](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) along with [standard page](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice?), it would really improve new user experience, since most of them can't clearly understand difference between superuser, askubuntu & serverfault...

Comment: related: [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773) and [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/165773)

Comment: Oh, lol, I guess my post should be merged with [this research](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279661/usability-issues-for-first-time-stack-exchange-users-a-micro-study). @ArtOfCode has done considerably more work to help to improve the way new users feel, it would be unfair if my simple CSS fix will be deployed before usability improvements suggested in his post :)