# What's the protocol for requesting a tag warning?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, tag-warnings

On a particular site, RPG Stack Exchange, we've decided on our meta on a couple of tags that should have tag warnings, and on what those tag warnings should say. I am a diamond moderator on the site in question.

What should we do to get the tag warnings implemented? Do we do any/all of the following?:

- start a [feature-request] on our meta for the tag warnings?
- raise a CM escalation?
- contact staff via the contact form?
- ping a staff member in the Teacher's Lounge?
- anything else?

Comment: Sorry if it sounds trivial, but... what exactly are tag warnings? You mean blacklisted tags? Edit: [Found it on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/447356). If it is specific to SO, better post this question on MSO too. (Same way questions about Triage, Documentation, Jobs, etc. go there)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, that's what they are. This is not an SO-specific feature -- Biology.SE is using them as well.

Comment: I see. Pity it was announced on SO in that case. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Might be one of those "don't tell everyone because we don't want to use it often" things? :)

Comment: ([RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). [CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354). [Teachers' Lounge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/teachers-lounge/info).)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Start with a post on the site's meta. This lets the community weigh in on the request, and also gives a paper trail in the event it is implemented. Figure out both whether this is needed and work on drafting the text for the warning so the CMs have some context and know what wording you think would be good.

Once the community has voted on the post and there is a consensus that it should be done, then you'd need a member of SE Staff to take the next steps.

A site mod should add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to the question, which will bring it to the CMs' attention and be added to their backlog through the [staff escalation process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca). If it's been a while since you heard anything, try pinging a Community Manager in chat like a mod-only chat room asking to take a look at the request.

CM escalations are for issues about specific users, so that's not a great option here.

Comment: It seems that it is rather difficult to persuade a CM to create a tag warning. At least that's what I gather based on the [response from a moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/83225/2019/4/21) when tag warnings were discussed on [math.se].  Let us hope that moderators will get the ability to add tag warnings and then the process will become a bit smoother. I have seen that the feature request about this is marked (status-review): [Give moderators the power to add tag warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338875).