# Is it possible (and desirable) to add a global 'About' link, going to `/help/on-topic`, for all sites?

Tags: feature-request

It is currently *not* easy to find the description of what is on-topic for a given stack exchange site - at least not until you know how! I've been more or less involved with various stack exchange sites for a few years now, and I never did understand how to find this.

The help button is fairly hidden away and small, and even when you find the help pages, then there usually just seems to be a fairly large bunch of different pages about 'Asking'. However, in fact, for (almost?) all stack exchange sites, just take the base URL and add `/help/on-topic` and you will find the page I wanted all along.

I think it would be extremely useful if the left-hand links on any given stack exchange site included an 'About' link, which always links to the `/help/on-topic` page of that site.

If you try this for a few different sites, you will see that this given page very much does serve as an 'About' page for that site.

I think that this is something that a great many people are going to want to find, and that is also really quite hard to find at the moment.

The suggested change would make it more or less self evident (and arguably as another desirable side effect might help a bit in keeping first questions on topic?).

**@TheLethalCoder** has produced the following image, which very much captures what I am suggesting here (includes [tour], [help], [help/on-topic] & [help/dont-ask] links, as discussed in comments):

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a good idea to add a help / how to ask link to the left side bar. It would be easy to access and fill up a bit of that empty space. If anyone actually would read it before posting is a different matter.

Comment: Better to point it to the [tour] if you're going to have it.

Comment: Did you know posting `[help/on-topic]` resolves as [help/on-topic] on any site towards the relevant help center?

Comment: Hi @Mast Sorry, I genuinely don't understand what you mean by 'posting' `[help/on-topic]` - posting it where? How?

Comment: @MikeBeaton If you type it in a comment. There similar ones like `[tour]` becoming [tour].

Comment: Those are called "magic links" and full list can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000).

Comment: @TheLethalCoder With respect, I think I disagree. I did not know about the tour either until your comment. How *are* users supposed to stumble on these things? So *maybe* it could indeed do with a link too. But I think help/on-topic is much more likely to actually be read; it is much more focused, whereas the Tour seems much less quickly digestible. Even though I can see that the tour is probably *designed* to be more what someone wants, when they are thinking "what is this site about?", I really don't think it actually *is*.

Comment: .ShadowWizardisEarForYou and .TheLethalCoder You mean that if I include that link in a post or comment then it will work as shown? Okay, understood! And no, I didn't know that. It's useful to know. But for all that, I don't think it makes the suggestion in my OP any less desirable? (I'm not sure if that was intended as an implication by .Mast or not.)

Comment: @MikeBeaton The tour _should_ give more information on how the site works, what is and _isn't_ on topic etc. And is _supposed_ to be more easily readable with small chunks of information rather than long paragraphs like the help center but YMMV.

Comment: My mileage does vary, looking at the tour and help/on-topic for various sites, help/on-topic is exactly the focused information I was looking for but didn't know how to find.

Comment: How about adding 'On Topic' and 'Tour' links to each site?

Comment: The Tour is more of a general about page which I thought was more what you was asking about trying to find but adding both would likely be more preferable if implemented. Maybe even customisable per site with a link to the tour then a "help" section which links to help and has an area that each site can customise what they want to add.

Comment: The trouble with links to 'Help' per se is that it's *really* not obvious that it has this *one* absolutely essential page nested inside of it.

Comment: I did pretty clearly say that I was trying to find "find the description of what is on-topic for a given stack exchange site"! That would still be pretty much by-the-by if it was just what *I'm* trying to find - but I don't think it is. I think it's *exactly* what a lot of people will want to find. Many more people than will would want the whole Tour per se, actually, IMHO.

Comment: I think something like this might be what you're after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DSRp.png I just knocked it up _very_ quickly but is an idea.

Comment:  Yes, that looks absolutely ideal!

Comment: You may want to edit the image into your post. Though to be honest I do like the idea of the help bullets being customisable per site.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know who gets to decide. On the principle of 'keep it simple' I'd still - at least initially - just go with one size fits all. Is there a standard link for help/off-topic (which doesn't seem to work)? I tried editing the image into my post, but it takes up a ton of space, I think I'll leave it down here - thank you for it, though!

Comment: @MikeBeaton _"I don't know who gets to decide"_ Well if implemented SE does initially. After that it'd likely be the meta community/mods like with the [new ask page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/345161). And it is `/help/dont-ask`. A lot of the "early" stuff isn't too consistent.

Comment: And side note, stack uses imgur for hosting so the "size modifiers" work like usual. If you use `m`, https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DSRpm.png, the image is smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes what's on-topic is more aptly defined in one of the `faq` tags on the site's Meta.

It's true that `/help/on-topic` can be edited by the sites' moderators.

That link doesn't seem to be in the new "Ask" help -- [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/139866) -- that seems to me an oversight, maybe they will correct that.

And/or a site can customise that help, by following the same procedure as for a tag warning -- [What's the protocol for requesting a tag warning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298887/139866)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Would you have time to elaborate a little more specifically as to how these points bear on whether it is possible and desirable to add links something like I suggested?

Comment: The first 2 sentences are to say that `/help/on-topic` isn't the only place where "on-topic" is defined -- it's often defined in FAQs on Meta -- but site moderators can control that.

Comment: The next two sentences are to say that instead of your suggestion (i.e. the left sidebar) there's now another place where that link might be useful and timely -- and which doesn't depend of SE implementing a new feature request which they might be unlikely to.

Comment: So when you say 'a site can customise that help, by following [etc.]' by 'that help' you mean the help modal for new askers? That might arguably have the disadvantages that you can't find it unless you've already decided to answer a question, and that you won't see those links again as soon as you're not a new asker.

Comment: With regard to faq tags, do you have an example of a stack exchange site where `help/on-topic` wouldn't be useful but searching for the `faq` tag in the site's meta-site would be? If that is the case in some sites, would that be *even* harder for most users to find, again?! And wouldn't it be easy to put a link to that in help/on-topic, *if* it was needed? (Thus still working with the suggestion I'm making here?)

Comment: I think "those links" are visible every time a new question is asked, and not only if/while you're a new asker. I guess you're disappointed by my answer that it doesn't match your suggestion more closely, but it has one advantage of already having been implemented i.e. being practical.

Comment: If it is shown for all questions, then I'm only disappointed because as I said, "you [won't] find it unless you've already decided to [ask and compose] a question". Less importantly, I've just tested it and it didn't appear when I created (and deleted!) a test question, so it seems that that help text is *not* (unfortunately) visible every time a question is asked. I agree it would be simpler to modify an existing feature if it served the same purpose. My first objection (as repeated first in this comment) remains my biggest objection to your suggestion, which otherwise meets that desideratum.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a free [open-source](https://github.com/MikeBeaton/SEHelpLinks) [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-exchange-help-links/ckpachebenneicjfndebehniipdlhncc) which actually adds these links to all Stack Exchange sites.

[image]

It now supports:

- stackoverflow.com
- *.stackexchange.com
- superuser.com
- serverfault.com
- askubuntu.com
- stackapps.com

which all work with exactly the same code.

I'm not suggesting this is the best permanent solution - far from it. But it does make it very easy to evaluate how well this works. Personally, I'm definitely planning to leave this installed for myself on my own browser, for now - I find these extra links very useful!

Thanks **@TheLethalCoder** for additional link suggestions.